# Pulling group name programmatically

Tags: 7, theming, organic-groups

I am setting up a pre-process function to add the title of an OG group to the title of the image field of the same group. The idea is to have the name of the group show when the mouse cursor hovers above the group image if no title is given to the image when the group is created.

Here is what I have thus far:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_image(&$vars) {
  if (empty($vars['attributes']['title'])) {
  $vars['attributes']['title'] = $group_node;
 }
}
```

Somehow I cannot grab the name of the group node. What am I doing wrong? Is there a particular way group names are handled?

Comment: `hook_preprocess_image()` doesn't know anything about groups. In fact, it is invoked also when the Organic groups module is not enabled or installed.

Comment: In other words, `hook_preprocess_image()` is invoked for every image shown with `theme('image')`, not just the images added with the image field to some nodes.